# \AddEverypageHook just checks the first page

Tags: page-breaking, backgrounds, hooks

I am totally new to LaTeX and right now I'm trying to find out how everything works. For the following code I get a background picture only on the first page although I want to have it on all odd pages. Additionally I get an error stating:

```
Undefined control sequence: \AddEverypageHook
```

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\newcommand\BackgroundPic{
\put(-4,0){
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,
keepaspectratio]{background.jpg}%
\vfill
}}}

\makeatletter
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}%
  {}%
  {\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\title{The Triangulation of Titling Data in
       Non-Linear Gaussian Fashion via $\rho$ Series}
\date{October 31, 475}
\author{John Doe\\ Magic Department, Richard Miles University
        \and Richard Row, \LaTeX\ Academy}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

It would be nice if you could help me with this and explain what is going wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`eso-pic` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) does *not* provide `\AddEverypageHook`, hence the "Undefined control sequence" error. The latter is provided by the [`everypage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/everypage). However, since `eso-pic` loads [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) by default, you can use the functionality provided by it to tap into the page output routine.

It seems like you're after printing some background image on every odd/even page of your document. The following does that:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}% http://ctan.org/pkg/babel
%\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{ifthen}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen
\usepackage{blindtext}% http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic

\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
  \put(-4,0){%
    \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
      \vfill
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{tiger}%
      \vfill
  }}}

%\makeatletter
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}%
    {}%
    {\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\BackgroundPic}}%
}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}


\title{The Triangulation of Titling Data in
       Non-Linear Gaussian Fashion via $\rho$ Series}
\date{October 31, 475}
\author{John Doe\\ Magic Department, Richard Miles University
        \and Richard Row, \LaTeX\ Academy}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Here are some further considerations:

- To place an image in the "background layer", `eso-pic` offers `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` while `\AddToShipoutPictureFG` prints it in the "foreground layer". Each have a starred variant pertaining to *only* that page it's called on. There is no `\AddToShipoutPicture` (without `BG` or `FG`).
- The picture addition is based on `\value{page}`, so any command that influences page numbering has an effect on the placement (like your title).

Comment: thanks a lot for the fast answer. This helped me a lot :).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution by *xwatermark* package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage[colorlinks,pdfview=FitB]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}[2012/02/01]
% Local watermark locations:
\watermarkpaths{{./}{./Graphics/}}
% \newwatermark has a key-value interface. There are many more keys; see the 
% package documentation. 'oddpages' means 'put watermarks on odd pages only'.
\newwatermark[
  oddpages,coordunit=pc,fontfamily=put,textcolor=BurntOrange,fontsize=5cm,
  textalign=center,textangle=45,picangle=0,textxpos=-4,textypos=4,picxpos=0,
  picypos=0,picontoptext,picbb=127 203 527 672,picscale=.6,picfile=mindmap1,
  picfileext=pdf
]{MIND}
% Get the dimensions of the graphics 'comet1':
\xwmgetpicdim[scale=.5,viewport=20 21 590 400]{comet1}
% Put 'comet1' on odd pages, at the given positons:
\repeatwatermarks[Page=\thepage]{%
  oddpages,coordunit=pc,picbb=20 21 590 400,picscale=.5,picfile=comet1,
  textontoppic,fontsize=2.5cm,textcolor=white
}{%
  picxpos=-.5\paperwidth+\xwmwdofpic/2,picypos=-.5\paperheight+\xwmtothtofpic/2,
  textxpos=-.5\paperwidth+\xwmwdofpic/2,textypos=-.5\paperheight+\xwmtothtofpic/2;
  picxpos=-.5\paperwidth+\xwmwdofpic/2,picypos=.5\paperheight-\xwmtothtofpic/2,
  textxpos=-.5\paperwidth+\xwmwdofpic/2,textypos=.5\paperheight-\xwmtothtofpic/4;
  picxpos=.5\paperwidth-\xwmwdofpic/2,picypos=-.5\paperheight+\xwmtothtofpic/2,
  textxpos=.5\paperwidth-\xwmwdofpic/2,textypos=-.5\paperheight+\xwmtothtofpic/2;
  picxpos=.5\paperwidth-\xwmwdofpic/2,picypos=.5\paperheight-\xwmtothtofpic/2,
  textxpos=.5\paperwidth-\xwmwdofpic/2,textypos=.5\paperheight-\xwmtothtofpic/4
}

\begin{document}
xx
\newpage
yy
\newpage
zz
\newpage
aa
\newpage
bb
\end{document}
```

The image shows only page 1 of the output.

[image]